# How can I assign this delegate with variable arguments

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I get the following error when trying to use a delegate with variable number of parameters:

> Error 39  Using the generic type
>   'SlotManager.OrdersConnection.delNewOrderSingle' requires
>   6 type arguments

What am I doing wrong?

```
public delegate QuickFix.Message delNewOrderSingle<A,B,C,D,E>(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e);
public delegate QuickFix.Message delNewOrderSingle<A, B, C, D, E, F>(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f);

public virtual QuickFix.Message AgnosticNewOrderSingle42LIMITtest(char side, string symbol, decimal amount, decimal price)
{

            delNewOrderSingle newOrderSingle = new QuickFix.FIX44.NewOrderSingle(
                    new ClOrdID(masterForm.OrderBook.GetNewClOrdIDBroker(ecn.brokerCode)),
                    new Symbol(symbol),
                    new Side(side),
                    new TransactTime(DateTime.Now),
                    ordType = new OrdType(OrdType.LIMIT));


}
```

> NOTE: From Sean's comment I see the question is very wrong. Please see
>   this follo-up

[Is it possible to change cast of an object dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985539/is-it-possible-to-change-cast-of-an-object-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to assign an instance of `NewOrderSingle` to a delegate. You need to assign a method to the delegate, not an object instance.

Also, as the delegate is generic you need to specify the generic types

Did you mean to do this:

```
delNewOrderSingle<ClOrdID, Symbol, Side, TransactTime, OrdType> newOrderSingle = (a,b,c,d,e) =>  new QuickFix.FIX44.NewOrderSingle(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Comment: Ah yes. It is NOT a method - what should I use instead of delegate? I want something that "points" to 2 different type of classes...

Comment: @ManInMoon - you'll need to explain what you're trying to accomplish in order for me to try to help!

Comment: I have re-asked the right question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985539/is-it-possible-to-change-cast-of-an-object-dynamically